# "Ambiguous type variable" when using scoped variables in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I got this OCaml code:

```ml
for x = 0 to 12 do
    let i = (1 + (x * 3)) in
    let j = (60 - (x * 5)) in
    Printf.printf "I=%d J=%d\n" (i) (j);
done;;
```

And I translated it to Haskell, but it wouldn't work:

```hs
import Text.Printf

for list action = mapM_ action list

main :: IO ()
main = do
    for [0..12] $ \x -> do
        let i = (1 + (x * 3))
            j = (60 - (x * 5)) in
            printf "I=%d J=%d\n" i j :: IO ()
```

The first error was:

> Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from the arithmetic sequence ‘0 .. 12’ prevents the constraint ‘(Enum t0)’ from being solved.

So I had to move the code inside the loop into a new function, then it worked:

```hs
import Text.Printf

for list action = mapM_ action list

block :: Int -> IO ()
block x = 
    let i = 1 + (x * 3)
        j = 60 - (x * 5) in
        printf "I=%d J=%d\n" i j :: IO ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
    for [0..12] $ \x -> do block x
```

So my question is: Does Haskell allow variables to be declared inside a inner scope? If yes, what did I miss?

Tested on replit.com

Comment: I have no issues running this in GHCi.

Comment: Please *don't* use `for` this is really very *un*-Haskellish.

Comment: I'd try to be more specific on the types, e.g. using `[0..12 :: Int]`. With that the original code should work, I guess.

Comment: I agree @WillemVanOnsem, but that code was generated by a code generation tool (which I'm creating). It produces code in 23 different languages, but it's somewhat limited because it won't use full resources of each language.

Comment: @chi , that has worked for me. Thanks. Feel free to post your answer if you wish.

Comment: @MuriloPerrone: well likely because it originates from *procedural programming*, and thus simply takes a program and almost literally translates it. But that is typically not how you should work with functional programming.

Comment: Good. The answer below explains it very well. No need for another answer. :-)

Comment: Aside,`Data.Foldable.for_` is better here because `for` produces a list of results that you don’t use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this snippet:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    for [0..12] $ \x -> do
        let i = (1 + (x * 3))
            j = (60 - (x * 5)) in
            printf "I=%d J=%d\n" i j :: IO ()
```

there's no explicit indication of which numeric type is being used here.  This would type check whether `0`, `12`, etc. were `Int`s, `Integer`s, `Word64`s, `Double`s or `Complex` numbers.

In certain, limited circumstances, GHC will "default" an unknown numeric type to either `Integer` or `Double` depending on how it's used, but this relies on the unknown type being constrained to a limited set of "built-in" type classes, and the use of `printf` introduces an additional type class constraint that interferes with this defaulting process.  If you avoided the use of `printf`, the type defaulting would work as intended, so the following works (with the numeric type defaulting to `Integer`):

```
import Text.Printf

for list action = mapM_ action list

main :: IO ()
main = do
    for [0..12] $ \x -> do
        let i = (1 + (x * 3))
            j = (60 - (x * 5)) in
            putStrLn $ "I=" ++ show i ++ " J=" ++ show j
```

Alternatively, if you added a type signature to explicitly indicate which numeric type you wanted to use, it would also work:

```
import Text.Printf

for list action = mapM_ action list

main :: IO ()
main = do
    for [(0::Int)..12] $ \x -> do
    --     ^^^^^
        let i = (1 + (x * 3))
            j = (60 - (x * 5)) in
            printf "I=%d J=%d\n" i j :: IO ()
```

You can also give type signatures in a `let` statement, so this would work too:

```
import Text.Printf

for list action = mapM_ action list

main :: IO ()
main = do
    for [0..12] $ \x -> do
        let i, j :: Int
        --  ^^^^^^^^^^^
            i = (1 + (x * 3))
            j = (60 - (x * 5)) in
            printf "I=%d J=%d\n" i j :: IO ()
```

Basically, anything that lets GHC figure out the type will fix this error.  The reason your version that uses `block` works is that `block` has a type signature that determines the numeric type as `Int`.  If you'd left out that type signature, you would have had the same error:

```
import Text.Printf

for list action = mapM_ action list

-- comment out the type signature, and it fails
-- block :: Int -> IO ()
block x = 
    let i = 1 + (x * 3)
        j = 60 - (x * 5) in
        printf "I=%d J=%d\n" i j :: IO ()

main :: IO ()
main = do
    for [0..12] $ \x -> do block x
```